# asp.net generate controls dynamically

Tags: asp.net, controls

I want to generate a navigator (not a site navigator) like the following,

`You are here: PCS > PCS_Five > PCS_Five_Three > PCS_Five_Three_3 >`

There my requirements are

The PCS, PCS_Five, PCS_Five_Three, PCS_Five_Three_3 should be `<a></a>` tags with id. The id will be hidden. Which control is most suitable with this task. I will generate it dynamically. Should I go for `Label` or `Literal` or just use `div` and append the `<a>`s dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Repeater` control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it anyway you prefer, but the feature is called breadcrumb and there are various free controls on web that are available for this sort of control. Like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/breadcrumbs.aspx) one.